# Extensions of Abelian groups to non-Abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

Let $N$ and $M$ be two finite Abelian groups. Is there a nice way to characterize all extensions of $M$ by $N$? I have seen a few sources where Abelian extensions of Abelian groups are discussed but we are interested in all (both non-Abelian and Abelian) extensions. Any comment could be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Such extensions are characterised by the second group cohomology $H^2(M,N)$. For example, with $M=C_2$ and $N=C_3$ we have also extensions to nonabelian groups, i.e.,
$$
1\rightarrow C_3 \rightarrow S_3\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow 1.
$$ 
In other words, the symmetric group $S_3$ is an extension of $C_3$ by $C_2$. Of course, we also have the extension 
$$
1\rightarrow C_3 \rightarrow C_6\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow 1.
$$

Comment: Sorry I have a very basic knowledge in this area. I came across the cohomology and its relation to group extensions but I am looking for something more basic that I could understand. Long time ago, I remember I had seen somewhere that extensions are characterized by two mappings satisfying some conditions. Would you happen to know of a result like that?

Comment: Yes, you mean factor systems. But you will see, that also $2$-cocycles are mappings satisfying "some conditions", and that it is not difficult.